# Replicating conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble using Conditional Formatting in Excel. No problem with setup for one row, but no luck replicating it to the rest of the worksheet.

```
         A            B         C             D
1    MATCH_RESULT   CODE    DESCRIPTION    CHECKUP                  
2       #N/A         A1       Chair         #N/A
3       #N/A         B1       Window        #N/A
4         2          C1       Table         #N/A
```

The goal is to identify if column A is filled with value #N/A (default error message for MATCH function). If it is, cells in columns - A, B, C - ONLY ON THE SAME ROW should be formatted (with color red). I.e. as per example, A2:C3 should be formatted.

This is working for me, however just for the first row and I fail to correctly replicate this downwards.

I'm selecting A2:C2 -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

I will end up with the formatting setup such as:

Formula: =$A$2=$D$2
Applies to: =$A$2:$C$2

A2 through C2 will be formatted, as expected (due to A2=D2). However I can't replicate the same thing on next rows. Format painter function will expand the current functionality so that still A2=D2 match is looked at for formatting other rows, instead of A3=D3 and so on.

Pretty sure the key is in $, but nothing has worked yet. Also pretty sure Excel allows just one cell in column D to be populated with value #N/A for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three issues, first your range is (part of) a single row `=$A$2:$C$2`. Try selecting ColumnsA:C before adding the rule, or change Applies to to:

```
=$A:$C
```

Second, you have anchored the row references in your formula. The 'style' should be:

```
=$A1=$D1
```

However your third issue is that comparing errors (`#N/A` resulting from a function) returns ... `#N/A` (so I don't know how you managed to get even a single row to work, since CF needs a `TRUE` result to trigger).

Maybe try:

```
=AND(ISNA($A1),ISNA($D1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the formula part with

```
=iserror($A2)
```

you may need to remove the $ manually.